# Trouble with keyframe animation for cycling text carousel

Tags: html, css, css-animations, keyframe

I have a text carousel that I am trying to adapt for my needs but I can't seem to fix the issue I am having. What I have are reviews that cycle one after the other in an infinite loop. The problem is after the third review cycles there is a large amount of blank time between the third review and first review that comes around again. Do I need to mess with the percentages on each keyframe cycle set until I get them lined up enough to cycle smoothly without the giant blank space at the end? If so, what is the best way to go about that?

```css
.content-slider {
 width: 400px;
 height: 360px;
 text-align: center;
}

.book-headline {
 font-size: 24px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: underline;
}

.slider {
 height: 320px;
 width: 400px;
 margin: 20px auto 0;
 overflow: visible;
 position: relative;
}

.mask {
 overflow: hidden;
 height: 320px;
}

.slider ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 position: relative;
}

.slider li {
 width: 400px;
 height: 320px;
 position: absolute;
 top: -325px;
 list-style: none;
}

.slider .quote {
 font-size: 20px;
 font-style: italic;
}

.slider .source {
 font-size: 15px;
 text-align: right;
}

.slider li.anim1 {
 -moz-animation: cycle 15s linear infinite;
 -webkit-animation: cycle 15s linear infinite;
 animation: cycle 15s linear infinite;
}

.slider li.anim2 {
 -moz-animation: cycle2 15s linear infinite;
 -webkit-animation: cycle2 15s linear infinite;
 animation: cycle2 15s linear infinite;
}

.slider li.anim3 {
 -moz-animation: cycle3 15s linear infinite;
 -webkit-animation: cycle3 15s linear infinite;
 animation: cycle3 15s linear infinite;
}
.slider:hover li {
 -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
 -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
 animation-play-state: paused;
}

@-moz-keyframes cycle {
 0% {
  top: 0px;
 }
 4% {
  top: 0px;
 }
 16% {
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 0;
 }
 20% {
  top: 325px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 0;
 }
 21% {
  top: -325px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
 }
 92% {
  top: -325px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 0;
 }
 96% {
  top: -325px;
  opacity: 0;
 }
 100% {
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
 }
}

@-moz-keyframes cycle2 {
 0% {
  top: -325px;
  opacity: 0;
 }
 16% {
  top: -325px;
  opacity: 0;
 }
 20% {
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
 }
 24% {
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
 }
 36% {
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 0;
 }
 40% {
  top: 325px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 0;
 }
 41% {
  top: -325px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
 }
 100% {
  top: -325px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
 }
}

@-moz-keyframes cycle3 {
 0% {
  top: -325px;
  opacity: 0;
 }
 36% {
  top: -325px;
  opacity: 0;
 }
 40% {
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
 }
 44% {
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
 }
 56% {
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
 }
 60% {
  top: 325px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 0;
 }
 61% {
  top: -325px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
 }
 100% {
  top: -325px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
 }
}


@-webkit-keyframes cycle {
 0% {
  top: 0px;
 }
 4% {
  top: 0px;
 }
 16% {
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 0;
 }
 20% {
  top: 325px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 0;
 }
 21% {
  top: -325px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
 }
 50% {
  top: -325px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
 }
 92% {
  top: -325px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 0;
 }
 96% {
  top: -325px;
  opacity: 0;
 }
 100% {
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
 }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cycle2 {
 0% {
  top: -325px;
  opacity: 0;
 }
 16% {
  top: -325px;
  opacity: 0;
 }
 20% {
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
 }
 24% {
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
 }
 36% {
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 0;
 }
 40% {
  top: 325px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 0;
 }
 41% {
  top: -325px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
 }
 100% {
  top: -325px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
 }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cycle3 {
 0% {
  top: -325px;
  opacity: 0;
 }
 36% {
  top: -325px;
  opacity: 0;
 }
 40% {
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
 }
 44% {
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
 }
 56% {
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 0;
 }
 60% {
  top: 325px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 0;
 }
 61% {
  top: -325px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
 }
 100% {
  top: -325px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="content-slider">
    <div class="slider">
    <div class="mask">
        <ul>
            <li class="anim1">
                <div class="book-headline">This is a headline</div>
                <div class="quote">“Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
                adipiscing elit. Proin facilisis feugiat elit eu porta. 
                Fusce a leo mauris. Sed venenatis ultrices libero, eu 
                volutpat ante tristique eu.”</div>
                <div class="source">- People from Peopletown</div>
            </li>
            <li class="anim2">
                <div class="book-headline">This is a second headline</div>
                <div class="quote">“Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
                adipiscing elit. Proin facilisis feugiat elit eu porta. 
                Fusce a leo mauris. Sed venenatis ultrices libero, eu 
                volutpat ante tristique eu.”</div>
                <div class="source">- Person from Personhood</div>
            </li>
            <li class="anim3">
                <div class="book-headline">This is a third headline</div>
                <div class="quote">“Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
                adipiscing elit. Proin facilisis feugiat elit eu porta. 
                Fusce a leo mauris. Sed venenatis ultrices libero, eu 
                volutpat ante tristique eu.”</div>
                <div class="source">- Villager from Village</div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `@keyframes` animation you have given a gap of 40% in the last animation. You have completed the first animation at 20% second at 40% and third at 60%. In the remaining 40% all elements are defined to stay our of the container. To animate 3 elements smoothly, you should use a difference of approx 33%. Please check the snippet for codes.

Also, always add the default style rules along with the `browser-prefixed` one and try to make your job easy by doing some research on `@keyframes`. I think adding `animation-delay` could have made your work easier as you need not define three different rules for different elements.

```css
.content-slider {
 width: 400px;
 height: 360px;
 text-align: center;
}

.book-headline {
 font-size: 24px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: underline;
}

.slider {
 height: 320px;
 width: 400px;
 margin: 20px auto 0;
 overflow: visible;
 position: relative;
}

.mask {
 overflow: hidden;
 height: 320px;
}

.slider ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 position: relative;
}

.slider li {
 width: 400px;
 height: 320px;
 position: absolute;
 top: -325px;
 list-style: none;
}

.slider .quote {
 font-size: 20px;
 font-style: italic;
}

.slider .source {
 font-size: 15px;
 text-align: right;
}

.slider li.anim1 {
 -moz-animation: cycle 15s linear infinite;
 -webkit-animation: cycle 15s linear infinite;
 animation: cycle 15s linear infinite;
}

.slider li.anim2 {
 -moz-animation: cycle2 15s linear infinite;
 -webkit-animation: cycle2 15s linear infinite;
 animation: cycle2 15s linear infinite;
}

.slider li.anim3 {
 -moz-animation: cycle3 15s linear infinite;
 -webkit-animation: cycle3 15s linear infinite;
 animation: cycle3 15s linear infinite;
}
.slider:hover li {
 -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
 -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
 animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes cycle {
 0% {
  top: 0px;
 }
 4% {
  top: 0px;
 }
 29% {
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 0;
 }
 33% {
  top: 325px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 0;
 }
 34% {
  top: -325px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
 }
 92% {
  top: -325px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 0;
 }
 96% {
  top: -325px;
  opacity: 0;
 }
 100% {
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
 }
}

@keyframes cycle2 {
 0% {
  top: -325px;
  opacity: 0;
 }
 29% {
  top: -325px;
  opacity: 0;
 }
 33% {
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
 }
 34% {
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
 }
 62% {
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 0;
 }
 66% {
  top: 325px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 0;
 }
 67% {
  top: -325px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
 }
 100% {
  top: -325px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
 }
}

@keyframes cycle3 {
 0% {
  top: -325px;
  opacity: 0;
 }
 62% {
  top: -325px;
  opacity: 0;
 }
 66% {
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
 }
 67% {
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
 }
 94% {
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
 }
 98% {
  top: 325px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 0;
 }
 99% {
  top: -325px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
 }
 100% {
  top: -325px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
 }
}


@-moz-keyframes cycle {
 0% {
  top: 0px;
 }
 4% {
  top: 0px;
 }
 29% {
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 0;
 }
 33% {
  top: 325px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 0;
 }
 34% {
  top: -325px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
 }
 92% {
  top: -325px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 0;
 }
 96% {
  top: -325px;
  opacity: 0;
 }
 100% {
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
 }
}

@-moz-keyframes cycle2 {
 0% {
  top: -325px;
  opacity: 0;
 }
 29% {
  top: -325px;
  opacity: 0;
 }
 33% {
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
 }
 34% {
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
 }
 62% {
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 0;
 }
 66% {
  top: 325px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 0;
 }
 67% {
  top: -325px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
 }
 100% {
  top: -325px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
 }
}

@-moz-keyframes cycle3 {
 0% {
  top: -325px;
  opacity: 0;
 }
 62% {
  top: -325px;
  opacity: 0;
 }
 66% {
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
 }
 67% {
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
 }
 94% {
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
 }
 98% {
  top: 325px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 0;
 }
 99% {
  top: -325px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
 }
 100% {
  top: -325px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
 }
}


@-webkit-keyframes cycle {
 0% {
  top: 0px;
 }
 4% {
  top: 0px;
 }
 29% {
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 0;
 }
 33% {
  top: 325px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 0;
 }
 34% {
  top: -325px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
 }
 92% {
  top: -325px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 0;
 }
 96% {
  top: -325px;
  opacity: 0;
 }
 100% {
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
 }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cycle2 {
 0% {
  top: -325px;
  opacity: 0;
 }
 29% {
  top: -325px;
  opacity: 0;
 }
 33% {
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
 }
 34% {
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
 }
 62% {
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 0;
 }
 66% {
  top: 325px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 0;
 }
 67% {
  top: -325px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
 }
 100% {
  top: -325px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
 }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cycle3 {
 0% {
  top: -325px;
  opacity: 0;
 }
 62% {
  top: -325px;
  opacity: 0;
 }
 66% {
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
 }
 67% {
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
 }
 94% {
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
 }
 98% {
  top: 325px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 0;
 }
 99% {
  top: -325px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
 }
 100% {
  top: -325px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="content-slider">
    <div class="slider">
    <div class="mask">
        <ul>
            <li class="anim1">
                <div class="book-headline">This is a headline</div>
                <div class="quote">“Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
                adipiscing elit. Proin facilisis feugiat elit eu porta. 
                Fusce a leo mauris. Sed venenatis ultrices libero, eu 
                volutpat ante tristique eu.”</div>
                <div class="source">- People from Peopletown</div>
            </li>
            <li class="anim2">
                <div class="book-headline">This is a second headline</div>
                <div class="quote">“Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
                adipiscing elit. Proin facilisis feugiat elit eu porta. 
                Fusce a leo mauris. Sed venenatis ultrices libero, eu 
                volutpat ante tristique eu.”</div>
                <div class="source">- Person from Personhood</div>
            </li>
            <li class="anim3">
                <div class="book-headline">This is a third headline</div>
                <div class="quote">“Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
                adipiscing elit. Proin facilisis feugiat elit eu porta. 
                Fusce a leo mauris. Sed venenatis ultrices libero, eu 
                volutpat ante tristique eu.”</div>
                <div class="source">- Villager from Village</div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you for the advice Rajan! You explained my error very well, I appreciate it. I'll definitely take your advice and look into keyframes and animation delay more before I try messing with more keyframe code.

Comment: Happy to help :)